# What limits the number of buses, devices and functions on a PCI bus?

Tags: pci

I am learning the PCI/PCIe bus. I learned that:

- A PCI hierarchy can support at most 256 buses.
- A PCI bus can support at most 32 devices.
- A PCI device can have at most 8 functions.

I checked the [Configuration Header Type 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_configuration_space).

[image]

There's a `Device ID` field which spans 2 bytes. 2^16 is much greater than 256.

So where do the 256, 32 and 8 restrictions come from?

Comment: The device ID is like the part number. It is used during enumeration to figure out what driver to load. It is not necessarily unique in a machine. For example, two NICs of the same model will have the same device ID.

Comment: not an expert on this topic, but I'd expect PCIe to be pretty different from PCI with respect to this – in the end, PCIe is a switched bus with point-to-point links, and that's not comparable to what limits the number devices on a PCI bus.

Comment: @marcus surprisingly not that much. On the software side they are very similar, pcie was designed to work with basically a PCI driver

Comment: @PlasmaHH ah, true (which is why `lspci` is still useful on modern PCs). But, a PCIe switch can basically span up it's totally independent sub-tree, and I think the simple factual restrictions of PCI break down here, wouldn't they?

Comment: @marcus depends on how you address messages. Of you still have the 16 bit only, not all could talk to all others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an [answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_configuration_space#Technical_information):

> In addition to the normal memory-mapped and I/O port spaces, each
>   device function on the bus has a configuration space, which is 256
>   bytes long, addressable by knowing the **eight-bit PCI bus**, **five-bit
>   device**, and **three-bit function numbers** for the device (commonly
>   referred to as the BDF or B/D/F, as abbreviated from
>   bus/device/function). **This allows up to 256 buses, each with up to
>   32 devices, each supporting eight functions.**

[image]